# Eevee performance benchamark

Tags: 3d-view, performance, experimental-features, eevee-render-engine

Are there any figures for the system requirements of the new Eevee renderer, measured in something like stream processors/face given a certain material?

The current viewport has worked for me on low polygon meshes on very modest hardware, even cheap or old laptops (with ao off), and my complex landscape shader (lots of conditionals) works ok but is somewhat laggy, in non-edit mode on GTX 1050 ti.

I am soon going to build a new machine and want to be future-proof when blender 2.8 is out. Do I need the beefy 1080ti or would the GTX 1050 ti still be sufficient for the same things it used to be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it both about hardware and experimental development versions

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Certainly true. However do you know of any preliminary benchmarks. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HntAab0Z7tg appears somewhat choppy, put there the machine does encode video as well, so not a really good one.

Comment: I think you can in the most cases use the old test scenes because Eevee and cycles are for the most part compatible. And if you feal like it, upvote my question [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100004/how-do-i-hide-a-parent-objects-only-collection-gui-2-80?noredirect=1#comment176856_100004) and I think @Duarte Farrajota Ramos will be hated if he continue to off-topic all 2.80 questions that whas agreed on in the meta to be on topic

Comment: @AlfonsMarklén can you also  provide a link to _agreed on in the meta to be on topic_

Comment: [Are questions about the 2.8 branch on topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/are-questions-about-the-2-8-branch-on-topic)

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to use EEVEE on more than Cycles because EEVEE is based on approximations that produce more or less the same result as Cycles but isn't as flexible as Cycles because of that.

In Cycles you can add a sun with energy 100 if Filmic is enabled without problems but that will not have the same result in EEVEE (I think Cycles did get an update to deal with stuff like that outside Filmic)

The biggest advantage with EEVEE that I can see is that it allows you to make a lots of work with a accurate viewport but it will not be good enough for everything.

The version of 2.80 I used recently didn't have the translucent shader as an example but I just skip using that until I have everything else right and EEVEE can handle to get input it can't use.